# Adding a member into an object according condition

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next

Is it possible to add a property using a condition?

```
{
   ...state,
   (1==1 ? ParamA: ParamB): [1,2,3,4,5],
}
```

In the example above the result would be:

```
{
    name: "Daniel",
    age: 33,
    ParamA: [1,2,3,4,5]
}
```

Please, **do not** consider the condition `1==1`, it's just an example.

Comment: Wrap the condition in brackets `[ ... ]` - this is a computed property key.

Comment: @le_m it's returning to me that ParamA isn't defined

Comment: `[(1==1 ? "ParamA": "ParamB")]:` was the right solution. Tks guys

Comment: There is no spread "operator", your question has nothing to do with spread syntax, and it's certainly not using ES6 spread syntax (which is for arrays and arguments only)?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was:

```
[(1==1 ? "ParamA": "ParamB")]: [1,2,3,4,5]
```